# Помогите сделать анимацию при исчезновении CSS, JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Помогите сделать анимацию при исчезновении  CSS, JS

JS код

```
<script>
      document.getElementById('hide0').onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById('JSt0').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('JSt1').style.display = 'none';

    }


      document.getElementById('hide1').onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById('JSt0').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('JSt1').style.display = 'block';
    }
  </script>
```

Долго думал и придумал вот такое решение

```
 <script>

    $("#hide0").click(function(){ 
    $("#JSt0").animate({height: "hide"}, 1000);
    $("#JSt1").animate({height: "show"}, 1000);

    });



    $("#hide1").click(function(){ 
    $("#JSt1").animate({height: "hide"}, 1000);
    $("#JSt0").animate({height: "show"}, 1000);

    });
  </script>
```

Если у кого есть ещё варианты, пожалуйсто посоветуйте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-поводу решения, на котором вы остановились, которое вы указали в ответе, во первых таким способом вы просто сделаете элемент прозрачным, а не фактически скроете его со страницы, во вторых в jquery есть готовые функции для скрытия\отображения элементов `fadeOut` \ `fadeIn`. В 3-х, если у вас второй блок должен появляться на месте первого, то вашим способом их анимации начнут выполняться одновременно, что выглядит не очень. Поэтому лучше делать так:

```
$("#hide0").click(function(){ 

    $("#JSt0").fadeOut( 250, function() {
        $("#JSt1").fadeIn(250);
    });

});

$("#hide1").click(function(){ 

    $("#JSt1").fadeOut( 250, function() {
        $("#JSt0").fadeIn(250);
    });

});
```

Тогда сначала скроется один блок, потом на его месте появится другой, что не вызовет их "пересечения", момента, когда они будут видны оба во время анимации.

Answer (score 0):

Всем большое спасибо!
Остановился на этом решении

```
 <script>

    $("#hide0").click(function(){ 
    $("#JSt0").animate({opacity: "hide",}, 500);
    $("#JSt1").animate({opacity: "show"}, 500);

    });

    $("#hide1").click(function(){ 
    $("#JSt1").animate({opacity: "hide",}, 500);
    $("#JSt0").animate({opacity: "show"}, 500);

    });
  </script>
```